# EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1, address)xd84253e0

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, exc-bad-access

I keep getting this break point appear on my project which then causes the app to stop running.

It doesn't break in the thread results it seems to break on this line:

`[urlString appendString: [URLQueryGenerator createSearchURL]]`;

The method that that line of code is in is as follows:

```
- (void)loadData {

    [_appDelegate reloadFavourites];
    if (_appDelegate.properties.count < 1) {

        //Reset Results page number to one. Because the results are starting afresh.
       [self setCurrentSearchPage:1];
       [self.navigationItem setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Search Results", nil) ];

        //Create URL String
        NSMutableString *urlString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString: @""];
       [urlString appendString: [URLQueryGenerator createSearchURL]];
        NSLog(@"%@", urlString);

        [xmlParser parseXMLPage:urlString withDelegate:self];

        [v_loadingView setHidden:NO];
        //Do not release Parser here, released in dealloc()
        //[xmlParser release];
    }
    else
    {
        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
            [self loadCells];
        else
            [table reloadData];
    }
}
```

I have put a break point on the search button that i have which then takes me to the results page to see if i could debug whats happening but its not giving a clear indication as to why i keep getting this error.

I have tried enabling zombie Object on the project but this still doesn't give me any indication.

Its really bugging me because i don't know how i can debug it well enough to find out why its doing this!

Can any one help please?

Comment: Trie to replace  [URLQueryGenerator createSearchURL] with some harcoded string, just to see if that is really the line that breaks your code

Comment: @AntonijoDev Thankyou i tried that and it defiantly is that line of code it brings back results when i have hardcoded it :)

Comment: Then see why this class doesnt like the string U are passing to it, maybee it needs to be escaped or something

Comment: No problem, any time... :)